# Hybris flexible query is not working for Customer type

Tags: sql, sap-commerce-cloud

I run below query through
https://localhost:9002/console/flexsearch#

When I run below query there is no error

```
SELECT   
           *
            FROM { Customer  AS p} 
            where p_name IS NOT NULL
```

But, when I run this, it's giving me an error.

```
SELECT *
            FROM { Customer  AS p} 

            where {p_name} =' zohan'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confused between flexible and SQL query?

Hybris use flexible query syntax where you can simply use TypeCode (Customer) and their attribute(name) to make the query. Hybris internally convert your query to the respective database syntax. In DB each column name is prefixed with `p_`. So if you want to directly use SQL query you should use `p_name` otherwise with flexible search use model attributes name (`name` in your case)

### Flexible search syntax

```
SELECT * FROM {Customer} WHERE {name} IS NOT NULL
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM {Customer  AS c} WHERE {c.name} IS NOT NULL
```

### SQL query

you can run from `HAC > console > FlexibleSearch > SQL query`

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE p_name is not null
```

---

Refer [FlexibleSearch Samples](https://help.hybris.com/6.6.0/hcd/8bc33bb28669101481ccfb446695e9de.html) and other [Tips and Tricks](https://help.hybris.com/6.6.0/hcd/8bc36ba986691014b48be171221d1f4f.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you use Flexible Search, you need to refer to attributes and types by their code. Hybris translates this query then to an sql query. So in your case:

```
SELECT * FROM {Customer  AS p} WHERE {p.name} IS NOT NULL
```